# Mongodb connection failed using robomongo

Tags: mongodb, perl, sockets, authentication

I have to write a perl script to connect to mongodb. But I am not able connect to DB instance in my machine it is giving me the following error:

```
2016-09-19T12:54:03.257+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed
errno:10048 Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port
) is normally permitted. for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2016-09-19T12:54:03.257+0530 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets
 during startup.
2016-09-19T12:54:03.259+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

I tried checking if any other process is running on that port number, but for that particular PID there is no process running in the task manager.
 When I am using Robomongo it is showing authentication failed. I am new to MongoDB. Please help.

TIA.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to local MongoDB or remote? Where is your MongoDB hosted ?

Comment: What does `netstat -aon | findstr LISTENING | findstr 27017` give?

Comment: You may also try running it on different port: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--port

Comment: It is a local instance.

Comment: C:\windows\system32>netstat -aon | findstr LISTENING | findstr 27017
  TCP    0.0.0.0:27017          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11940

Comment: When I am giving any command regard MongoDB in my command prompt, it is saying"'--shell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."